# indirect variable expansion in POSIX as done in bash?

Tags: shell, shell-script, posix

Is it possible, or is there some elegant hack to do indirect variable expansion in POSIX as can be done in Bash?

For context, I'm trying to do the following:

```
for key in ${!map_*}
do
    # do something
done
```

EDIT: To clarify, I'd like to access shell variables that begin with `map_`.

Comment: Voted to reopen. The Q wants to know how to get indirectly, all the variables that match the wildcard (`map_*`).

Comment: I was surprised I was unclear with regards to my question :P

Comment: Please re-open. It's a case of `sh` VS `bash` -- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5725402/1172302.

Comment: So this is why some folks don't like stackoverflow and some stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hack is to use `eval`:

```
aaa=1
aab=2
aac=3

eval_like() {
    pattern=$1
    vars=`set |grep "^$pattern.*=" | cut -f 1 -d '='`
    for v in $vars; do
        eval vval="\$$v"
        echo $vval
    done
}   

for i in `eval_like aa`; do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: Thanks! `set` was what I was looking for.

Comment: That's not foolproof though and is an arbitrary command injection vulnerability (like when it's run in an environment that has `QUERYSTRING=$'\nmap_$(reboot)=x'`). Also beware that the `bash` shell includes the list of functions in the output of `set` (when not running as `sh`).