# Read command in shell script - variable input substitution

Tags: shell-script, terminal, read, variable-substitution

*I am new to Linux, pardon any wrong terminology used here.*

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I am reading text in a shell script using `read` command. I have a variable in bash window that I want to substitute in that read command. My shell script looks like this:

```
echo "Enter Text"
read text
echo "Text is $text"
```

Then I execute it like this in terminal

```
user@machine:~$ var="hello world"
user@machine:~$ ./script.sh
Enter text
$var
Text is $var
user@machine:~$
```

Notice the line in output - `Text is $var`.. how can I make it read the value of variable `var` so it stores `hello world` in variable named `text`?

NOTE:
I know there is an option to pass parameters to scripts, but I find this more intuitive for the user executing script hence wanted to know how to do it this way!

Comment: More intuitive, I don't know. Less efficient, certainly. You are preventing name completion. Bash will do completion on the names of environment variables. Try this: execute `export SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME="variable content"`. Then type `echo $SOME_L` and [tab][enter]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [indirect variable expansion in POSIX as done in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111618/indirect-variable-expansion-in-posix-as-done-in-bash)

Answer (score 4):

This is called [*indirection*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection), and the syntax is `${!reference}` to substitute the value of the variable whose name is in the `reference` variable. For example:

```
name='Jane Doe'
reference='name'
$ echo "${!reference}"
Jane Doe
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote.. someone else did on both the answers!

Comment: Also, I changed script.sh last line to `echo "Text is $text ${!text}"` and it threw an error on execution saying "./script.sh: line 3: $var: bad substitution."

Comment: Then you're most likely not running Bash. Or you're running [pre-4.3](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061).

Comment: @Shishir you don't have a shebang in your script, so it's run with sh, not bash

Comment: @l0b0 oh okay.. I am new to Linux. If it is running with sh, then how do I do it?

Comment: @muru AFAIK it'll run with your *current* shell, not necessarily `sh`. Do you have a counter-reference?

Comment: It depends on the shell, IIRC. Bash and ksh run it with itself, other shells may use sh (dash and zsh do).

Comment: I think it is dash. Does it matter?

Comment: See [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373223/73093), but the short answer is as muru said.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your variable first:

```
export var=test
```

Then, use `envsubst` to replace variables inside text:

```
echo "Enter Text"
read text
printf 'Text is %s\n' "$text" | envsubst
```

> **envsubst** - substitutes environment variables in shell format strings

Comment: Doesn't work. Empty output! Probably since $var is not an environment variable?

Comment: yes sure ... see my edit